# Number.toString returns "incorrect" hexadecimal value

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, hex

In order to utilize a third party API, I have to convert the ID number to a hexadecimal. I converted the ID with https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html and got `711DD21A11FA9223FEB43849FF1F3569DC024DCE000000000000150000000001`. This works when I use it with the API.

My understanding is that you can perform the same conversion with JS with `Number().toString(16)`. However, when I use that function I get `711dd21a11fa9400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

The latter value does not work with the API. Any insight into why the JS function returns a different value?

[image: Screenshot of public converter and JS script]

Comment: Note that the accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is too big for JavaScript.

> The [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript.

I advise you to use the [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) data type.

> BigInt is a primitive wrapper object used to represent and manipulate primitive bigint values - which are too large to be represented by the number primitive.

Exampe:

```js
// Your number in decimal
const decimalNumber = BigInt("10000000000000000");

// Your number in hex
const hexNumber = decimalNumber.toString(16);

console.log(`Decimal number: ${decimalNumber}`);
console.log(`Hex number: ${hexNumber}`);
```

Comment: This is not really the correct way to construct a BigInt constant. The problem is that the plain number argument to the `BigInt()` constructor will be parsed as a plain number, and therefore will be truncated *before* the `BigInt()` constructor is even called. The correct thing to do is either use a string representation and pass that to the constructor, or use `10000000000000000n` to make a BigInt constant directly.

Comment: You can verify by trying `BigInt(10000000000000007)`, and then note that the value comes out incorrectly (10000000000000008 instead).

Comment: You're right. I have corrected the answer based on your comments.